# jQuery serializeArray using $(this)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jQuery's serializeArray to serialize form data, in two different ways.

The "Save All Rooms" button serializes all the form data (this is working fine), and the "Check Availability" button serializes data only from the specific form the button is click for (this isn't working).

Can anyone advise where I'm going wrong? Any help much appreciated!

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kuohhm2q/

"Check Availability" function which isn't working:

```
// Serialize Individual Form Data
el.find(".check_availability" ).click(function() {

   var formData = JSON.stringify( $(this).parent('div :input').serializeArray() ); 
   alert(formData);

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed

```
 JSON.stringify( $(this).parent('div :input').serializeArray() );
```

to this

```
JSON.stringify($(this).parent('div').find("input, select").serializeArray() );
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kuohhm2q/2/)

Comment: Thanks, that was almost it although it doesn't get the data from the "select" option, I change it to the following and now it's working great    JSON.stringify($(this).parent('div').find("input, select").serializeArray() );

Comment: @TheBobster: Correct! Edited my code o reflect same.